# sklearn.TargetEncoder -> Target type was inferred to be 'multiclass'. Only ('binary', 'continuous') are supported

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a product data set with 21 columns.
one is the producer and the target is the price.
There are over 30 different producers so OneHotEncoding is out of question since I face "curse of dimensionality" cause this is not my only categorical columns.
I decided to use TargetEncoder for this column (note that the distribution of different producers are not in a way so I can discard any,  I have to keep them all)
However it gives me the above error

This is a part of the code:

```
f = data['manufacturer'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
g = data['price'].to_list()
enc_auto = TargetEncoder(smooth="auto")
f_trans = enc_auto.fit_transform(f, g)
```

As it is explained in the documentation I transformed both columns,
[https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.TargetEncoder.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

however it raises the following error.

```
ValueError: Target type was inferred to be 'multiclass'. Only ('binary', 'continuous') are supported.
```

- I tried transformed method for "f" instead of reshape (data['manufacturer'].to_numpy().T) and it gave a different error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

and if I use reshape(1, -1) it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 675413]
```

- fitting and then trnsforming gave similar errors (f_trans = enc_auto.fit(f, g).transform(f))

Can someone please tell me how should I do it?
It doesn't even make sense anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Use `target_type='countinuous` as parameter of `TargetEncoder` if you use a regression model:

```
f = data['manufacturer'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
g = data['price'].to_list()
enc_auto = TargetEncoder(target_type="continuous", smooth='auto')  # <- HERE
f_trans = enc_auto.fit_transform(f, g)
```

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.TargetEncoder.html):

> Note:
> The type of target inferred with "auto" may not be the desired target type used for modeling. For example, if the target consisted of integers between 0 and 100, then type_of_target will infer the target as "multiclass". In this case, setting target_type="continuous" will specify the target as a regression problem. The target_type_ attribute gives the target type used by the encoder.

Comment: It was target_type="continuous", I think you mistakenly said smooth. Thanks, it solved the issue.